# How do I drag my Excel formula horizontally across and vertically down, while keeping a relative reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: See sample table]

In the sheet (linked image aboveI've written the formula such that an "X" is inserted across my timeline for tasks that start and finish with the timeline column headers. The formula I've written is:

```
=IF(AND(G$2>=$C4,G$2<=$D4),"X","")
```

What I'd like to do is to replace the "X" with the "Avg hrs/Day" (column F).

I realized that while tweaking the formula in G4 as an example, I can't just reference cell F4 and drag it all the the way to the right and then down at the same time.

How can I accomplish this? This is just a sample table. The real table I have to apply this on has about 75 columns of dates in the timeline and 200 rows of tasks so I cannot change the relative reference row-by-row.

Comment: Drag it to the right first, release, then drag that new selection down.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the sample formula you provided is for cell G4. Can't you reference the `Avg hrs/Day` just like you reference the `Start` and `Finish` dates in columns C and D?

```
=IF(AND(G$2>=$C4,G$2<=$D4),$F4,"")
```

Like LPChip said in the comments above, put this formula in cell G4. Drag it all the way to the right, then release, then drag the new selection all the way down.

Answer (score 1):

Copy formula horizontally on Windows: Enter formula for the first cell. Select other cells on the same row, press <kbd>F2</kbd>, then simultaneously <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

**(DISCLAIMER: This works for google sheets, don't know if it works for excel)**

1. select the cell with the formula in it
2. press **Ctrl+X** if on windows, **Command+X** if on mac
3. select cell you would like to place formula in
4. press **Ctrl+V** if on windows, **Command+V** if on mac

It should automatically change the cell locations to be the same horizontal and vertical distance relative to the formula's new location, and in the same direction (up/down left/right)

Note: if you would like to copy instead of cut, replace any **X** in the key combos to a **C**. if this does not work, i recommend uploading your excel sheet to google sheets and trying again there